# Problem with curly bracket expression in .map function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

can you help me in how to swap the hard coded [0] for {row}. The problem is in escaping the outer wrapping {} brackets where inside the {row} should go.

I have tried various combinations of brackets and backticks etc. Sorry for the bad title.

Edit: I found the bug. The code works fine. The problem is in the array. Thank you for your quick answers.

```
return savedChallenges.map((row, i) => {
  if (i !== 0) {
    return (
      <List.Item key={row}>
        <List.Content>
          <List.Header>
            <Link to={`/challenges/${row}`}>{challenges[0].name}</Link>
          </List.Header>
          <List.Description>{challenges[0].submitter}</List.Description>
        </List.Content>
      </List.Item>
    );
  }
  return null;
});
```

Comment: Just use the `i` there...?

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to do

Comment: you should edit your question to make it clear

Comment: Unrelated, but I'd flip the logic expression and return early when `i === 0` so I don't have to read the entire method to know what happens.

Answer (score 0):

Inside the JSX `{...}` you can write all valid JS expressions.. So it will be like

1. `` <Link to={`/challenges/${row}`}>{challenges[i].name}</Link> ``
2. `<List.Description>{challenges[i].submitter}</List.Description>`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming row is your index you are trying to use...

```js
return savedChallenges.map((row, i) => {
  if (i !== 0) {
    return (
      <List.Item key={row}>
        <List.Content>
          <List.Header>
            <Link to={`/challenges/${row}`}>{challenges[row].name}</Link>
          </List.Header>
          <List.Description>{challenges[row].submitter}</List.Description>
        </List.Content>
      </List.Item>
    );
  }
  return null;
});
```